# How to change text selection color of UITextField?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield

Xcode9.2, iOS 11, swift

I'm working on a project where user have to enter some text using Keyboard. User can use English & Japanese keyboard. now, when i start typing using English keyboard it works good no problem at all. but when i change keyboard to Japanese and start entering a same character multiple times. it shows selected text in `UITextField`.

here is my `UITextField`setup,

```
    self.tf.font = self.font
    self.tf.textAlignment = .center
    self.tf.returnKeyType = .done
    self.tf.inputAccessoryView = nil
    self.tf.text = " "
    self.tf.tintColor = UIColor.clear
    self.tf.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
```

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want to change the text selection color? Or do you want to hide the text selection color?

Comment: @Carpsen90 somehow it should not be shown to user. so, i will choose short function.

Answer (score 2):

To change the text selection color of a `UITextField` simply change the tint color property:

```
textField.tintColor = UIColor.purple
```